# How can I delete datapoint in Google matching engine index with Langchain

Tags: indexing, google-cloud-vertex-ai, langchain, google-ai-platform, vector-database

I'm working with Langchain's Matching Engine and I've gone through their documentation on integrating with VectorStores (https://python.langchain.com/docs/integrations/vectorstores/matchingengine). I've successfully implemented the creation of an index and an endpoint for data storage. However, I'm unclear about the process of deleting data from an index or, in simpler terms, deleting a datapoint.

The documentation provides comprehensive guidance on creating indexes and endpoints, but it seems to omit information about the process of deleting data. Could someone kindly guide me on how to effectively delete data from an index using Langchain? Are there specific methods or steps that I should follow to achieve this?

I appreciate any insights or code examples that can help clarify this aspect of using Langchain's Matching Engine. Thank you!

Comment: refer this https://python.langchain.com/docs/modules/data_connection/indexing